# How to set correctly the BlocProvider between two different routes (screens)?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am using **Bloc** for my application, however I was doing something wrong and that is, providing all BlocProvider creates in the `MaterialApp` and I would not like to follow that bad practice.

Let's suppose that when I navigate to **ScreenA**, we create the **Bloc** as follows :

```dart
      case PageNames.screenA:
        return PageTransition( // Some class that navigates
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          child: BlocProvider<ScreenABloc>(
            create: (context) => ScreenABloc(),
            child: const ScreenAPage(),
          ),
      );
```

Now inside **ScreenA**, I will do a navigation to **ScreenB**, and everything is fine, however inside **ScreenB** at the bottom of my widget tree I want to access the **ScreenABloc** again, but I can't assign a `BlocProvider.value` because I get :

`ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ScreenABloc> above this Welcome Widget`

```dart
return BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<ScreenABloc>(context),
      child: child ...
);
```

So I am not sure how to get the supplier that has already been created, or if I should re-create it or what to do in those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using all `BlocProviders` in the starting of the file is **not always considered bad practice.** as according to [official docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#blocprovider)

> By default, `BlocProvider` will create the bloc **`lazily`**, meaning create will get executed when the bloc is looked up via BlocProvider.of(context).

---

- So now, What are the use cases to use `providers` globally?

  > When you want to access the providers almost everywhere in the app.
- When to use `providers` passing through routes ?

  > When only some screens needs access to the `bloc` you can pass value using `BlocProvider.value`

---

According to the official docs of [`BlocProvider`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#blocprovider) in `flutter_bloc`,follow these steps to pass `BlocProvider` to the child screen.

##### Creation of `BlocA()`

```
BlocProvider(
  lazy: false,
  create: (BuildContext context) => BlocA(),
  child: ChildA(),
);
```

##### Passing the value of `BlocA` to `ScreenA()`

*Make sure this is called from inside the `ChildA()`*

```
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
  child: ScreenA(),
);
```

##### Now either from `ChildA` or `ScreenA` retrieve value as:

```
// with extensions
context.read<BlocA>();

// without extensions
BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the aclaration, but why in the Docs doesn't have an example of using the provider in the App ? Also i read this answers so ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/73278268/17023744

Comment: @DanielRoldán After research in the documentation,I figured out that drawbacks which is stated in that post you reffered is mostly overcomend in the latest update and there is no official link that the drawbacks stated in the post is actually from the creator of the bloc ,and even if its real, we dont know when were those stated, I have included all the possible scenario of using `specific` and `global bloc` and make sure you are passing the `BlocProvider.value` of `ScreeABloc` from within `ScreenABloc` where `ScreenABloc ` is provided with the `ScreenABloc`, only then `ScreenB` can access it.

Comment: Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method of creating `BlocProvider` in the screen itself, then you can use that method for navigating and creating providers for you.

Here's an example:

```js
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

   static Widget create() {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<SignInBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => SignInBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const SignInScreen(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `BlocProvider.value` when you push a new route:

```
/// declare the bloc
final _screenABloc = ScreenABloc();
```

then use it in both `ScreenA` and `ScreenB`

```
case PageNames.screenA:
  return PageTransition( // Some class that navigates
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    child: BlocProvider.value(
      value: _screenABloc,
      child: const ScreenAPage(),
    ),
  );

case PageNames.screenB:
  return PageTransition( // Some class that navigates
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    child: BlocProvider.value(
      value: _screenABloc,
      child: const ScreenBPage(),
    ),
  );
```